# picorv32 risc-v implementation in vivado 2018.2

Tags: c++, c, verilog, hdl, vivado

This is the core: 
https://github.com/cliffordwolf/picorv32

I'm having a problem implementing the core in vivado.
I have installed the riscv gnu toolchain and I am sure that it works ok, I modified the Makefile ($TOOLCHAINPREFIX).

I ran the makfile's make firmware.hex (from the scripts/vivado folder) and then I ran the make synth_system command to run synth_system.tcl in vivado and generate the bitstream for my fpga.

My fpga is an arty a7-35t development board and I have modified the synth_system.xdc constraints file to match the arty a7 pins and not the basys 3 (like it is by default). I also changed the name of the board in the .tcl script.
I also modified the firmware.c to only output zeros and ones on the adress 0x10000000 and with a small delay in between to blink the board's LED's.

However, de LED's don't blink, and the only efect is that the trap signal is on when I press the reset button (I put the reset on button0 of the FPGA and the trap signal on the green led 0).

So, whatever I do, the only result is the fact that I get a green LED light up when I press reset and that's all.

I may be missing something...

Please help me, I do not know what to do to fix this !

Thank you in advance !

P.S. I'm attaching the modified files from the scripts/vivado folder.

```
////////////////////////
firmware.c
///////////////////
void putc(int c)
{
(volatile int)0x10000000 = c;
}

void puts(const char *s)
{
while (*s) putc(*s++);
}

void *memcpy(void dest, const void src, int n)
{
while (n) {
n--;
((char)dest)[n] = ((char)src)[n];
}
return dest;
}

int message1=0xFFFFFFFF;
int message2=0x00000000;
int flag=1;

void main()
{

while(1)
{ 
    if(flag)
    {
        //putc(message2);
        *(volatile int*)0x10000000 = message2;
        flag=0;
    }
    else
    {   
        *(volatile int*)0x10000000 = message1;
        //putc(message1);
        flag=1;

    }

    for (long int i = 0; i=500000; i++);

}
}
```

```
////////////////////////////////////
synth_system.tcl
///////////////////////////////////

read_verilog system.v
read_verilog ../../picorv32.v
read_xdc synth_system.xdc

synth_design -part xc7a35ti-csg324-1L -top system
opt_design
place_design
route_design

report_utilization
report_timing

write_verilog -force synth_system.v
write_bitstream -force synth_system.bit
```

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////
synth_system.xdc
/////////////////////////////////////

XDC File for Arty A7 Board
###########################

set_property PACKAGE_PIN E3 [get_ports clk]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports clk]
create_clock -period 10.00 [get_ports clk]

Blue from RGB LEDS and also regular LEDS from Arty A7
set_property PACKAGE_PIN E1 [get_ports {out_byte[0]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {out_byte[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN G4 [get_ports {out_byte[1]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {out_byte[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN H4 [get_ports {out_byte[2]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {out_byte[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN K2 [get_ports {out_byte[3]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {out_byte[3]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN H5 [get_ports {out_byte[4]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {out_byte[4]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN J5 [get_ports {out_byte[5]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {out_byte[5]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T9 [get_ports {out_byte[6]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {out_byte[6]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T10 [get_ports {out_byte[7]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {out_byte[7]}]

first is buton 0 trap and out_byte_en is on green LEDS from the RGB leds
set_property PACKAGE_PIN D9 [get_ports {resetn}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {resetn}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN F6 [get_ports {trap}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {trap}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN J4 [get_ports {out_byte_en}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {out_byte_en}]

set_property CONFIG_VOLTAGE 3.3 [current_design]
#where value2 is the voltage provided to configuration bank 0

set_property CFGBVS VCCO [current_design]
#where value1 is either VCCO or GND

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

```
I also modified the code for system.v to see if the project works at all.
end else begin
//////////////////
last part of system.v
//////////////////////
always @(posedge clk) begin
m_read_en <= 0;
mem_ready <= mem_valid && !mem_ready && m_read_en;

        m_read_data <= memory[mem_addr >> 2];
        mem_rdata <= m_read_data;

        out_byte_en <= 0;
                    out_byte<=8'h0F;  ////MODIFIED PART
        (* parallel_case *)
        case (1)
            mem_valid && !mem_ready && !mem_wstrb && (mem_addr >> 2) < MEM_SIZE: begin
                m_read_en <= 1;
            end
            mem_valid && !mem_ready && |mem_wstrb && (mem_addr >> 2) < MEM_SIZE: begin
                if (mem_wstrb[0]) memory[mem_addr >> 2][ 7: 0] <= mem_wdata[ 7: 0];
                if (mem_wstrb[1]) memory[mem_addr >> 2][15: 8] <= mem_wdata[15: 8];
                if (mem_wstrb[2]) memory[mem_addr >> 2][23:16] <= mem_wdata[23:16];
                if (mem_wstrb[3]) memory[mem_addr >> 2][31:24] <= mem_wdata[31:24];
                mem_ready <= 1;
            end
            mem_valid && !mem_ready && |mem_wstrb && mem_addr == 32'h1000_0000: begin
                out_byte_en <= 1;
                out_byte <= 8'h01;  ///////////MODIFIED PART
                mem_ready <= 1;
            end
        endcase
    end
end endgenerate
endmodule
```

**I also tried to only lit the LEDs by while(1) writing 0xFF on them but that did not work either:**

```
void putc(int c)
{
    *(volatile int*)0x10000000 = c;
}

void puts(const char *s)
{
    while (*s) putc(*s++);
}

void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, int n)
{
    while (n) {
        n--;
        ((char*)dest)[n] = ((char*)src)[n];
    }
    return dest;
}

int message1=0xFFFFFFFF;
int message2=0x00000000;
int flag=1;

void main()
{
    while(1)
    {
    *(volatile int*)0x10000000 = message1;
    }

}
```

**Conclusion: even though the .C program writes at adress 0x1000_0000, the blue leds for the out byte only lit up in the pattern 0x0F (00001111 in binary, so only the latter 8 lit up)
Something must be wrong, I don't seem to find out what.**

Comment: I would strongly recommend trying a simulation of the design first.

Comment: Also, what toolchain prefix did you change it to? If it is a `linux` type gcc, then you will need to add `,--build-id=none` after `-Wl` in the firmware build command.

Comment: TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX = riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-
```


firmware.hex: firmware.S firmware.c firmware.lds
        $(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)gcc -Os -ffreestanding -nostdlib -o firmware.elf firmware.S firmware.c \
                 --std=gnu99 -Wl,-Bstatic,-T,firmware.lds,-Map,firmware.map,--strip-debug -lgcc
        $(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)objcopy -O binary firmware.elf firmware.bin
        python3 ../../firmware/makehex.py firmware.bin 4096 > firmware.hex
```
This is from the makefile I use to make the firmware.hex file. I use it on ubuntu 19.

Comment: also, all the scripts I used are in the scripts/vivado folder of the repo
the rest of them are called in the tcl script or in the makefile from the scripts/vivado folder

Comment: As you are using a `linux` toolchain, try the `build-id=none` trick above and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried, the build-id=none solution, also tried to do the vivado project manually to see if anything changes. No change in the behavior...

Comment: Can you put your firmware.hex on pastebin or similar?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FDYrd1CN
I attached the .lds and .s file which is needed to make the .hex from .c file.

Comment: I think you also need to add `-mabi=ilp32 -march=rv32i` to the gcc command line, as you are using a 64-bit compiler and you need to set it into 32-bit rv32i mode.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer, it now works like a dream. The code was not correctly 
synthesized. Can you please put it as an answer to the problem for all people who are using the riscv64 ? Thank you !

Comment: glad that it is working, answer added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to build code for a 32-bit RISC-V rv32i core using a 64-bit compiler (as most distributions provide) then you need to add `-mabi=ilp32 -march=rv32i` to put it into rv32i mode.

If you are using a "linux" variant compiler to create a bare metal binary, you need to remove the build ID (which breaks the flat binary output) by using `,--build-id=none` after `-Wl`.